# CakePHP clarification on using set() and compact() together. Will only work w/ compact()

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp, view, set

I know compact() is a standard php function. And set() is a cake-specific method.

I am running a simple test of passing a value to a view generated with ajax (user render() in my controller), and it only passes the value from the controller to the view if my setup is like so:

```
$variable_name_to_pass = "Passing to the view using set() can compact()";

$this->set(compact('variable_name_to_pass'));
```

From reading the manual, it appears set() should work along w/out compact.

Can anyone explain why set() will not work alone? Like

```
$this->set('variable_name_to_pass');
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

According to the [CakePHP API](https://api.cakephp.org/1.3/class-Controller.html#_set):

> Parameters:
>
> mixed `$one` required
>
> A string or an array of data.
>
> mixed `$two` *optional* NULL
>
> Value in case `$one` is a string (which then works as the key). Unused if `$one` is an **associative array**, otherwise serves as the values to `$one`'s keys.

The `compact` function returns an associative array, built by taking the names specified in the input array, using them as keys, and taking the values of the variables referenced by those names and making those the values. For example:

```
$fred = 'Fred Flinstone';
$barney = 'Barney Rubble';
$names = compact('fred', 'barney');

// $names == array('fred' => 'Fred Flinstone', 'barney' => 'Barney Rubble')
```

So when you use `compact` in conjunction with `set`, you're using the single parameter form of the `set` function, by passing it an **associative array** of key-value pairs.

If you just have one variable you want to set on the view, and you want to use the single parameter form, you must invoke `set` in the same way:

```
$variable_to_pass = 'Fred';
$this->set(compact('variable_to_pass'));
```

Otherwise, the two parameter form of `set` can be used:

```
$variable_to_pass = 'Fred';
$this->set('variable_to_pass', $variable_to_pass);
```

Both achieve the same thing.

Comment: Tokes, thanks for the clarification. I was a bit uncertain as to the exact function of these working together.

Comment: Any differences like compact is fast  when we having more number of variables.. Incase of Setting ?

Comment: how to view them in view file

Comment: Those looking for the up-to-date (at the moment of writing) info, here's documentation for 3.7: https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_set

Answer (score 4):

Compact returns an array. So, apparently set is checking it's parameters and if it's an array. It knows that it's from compact. If not it expects another parameter, the value of variable.