# Pass more than one variable from controller to view in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, view, controller, associative-array

I am new to `cakephp`. I need to send two variables to the `view`. In codeigniter its easy

```
$data['var1'] = 'One';
$data['var2'] = 'Two';
$this->load->view('myview',$data);
```

Now in `Cakephp`, I have a controller called function names `search()` in which I am sending an associative array to `view`.

```
$gal_providers = $this->GalProvider->getListByCategory(3,$location_id,false,9);
$this->set("gal_providers",$gal_providers);
```

But I need to send the variable `$location_id` too to the view. How can I send it ?

I read the article [Using set() and compact() together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477696/cakephp-clarification-on-using-set-and-compact-together-will-only-work-w-c), but I did not get the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Is this that you want? `$this->set('location_id',$location_id);` In your view you can use $location_id.
If isn't this, reformule your question pls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#create-a-posts-controller) describes very well how to set data to the view. I recommend you to do the tutorial first, it gives you all you need to do your first steps.

You can set variables using $this->set() in your controller:

```
$this->set('first', 'second');
$this->set(array('foo' => 'bar', 'something' => 'else'));
```

The first will make the variable $first with the value second available in the view. The second will make $foo with value bar and $something with value else available in the view.

Controll::set() is setting the data to the view instances viewVars property. When the view is rendered it turns them into variables available in the view templates.

And do yourself and other people who look at your code a favour and follow [the conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) and [coding standards](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html).