# Cakephp 3.0 tutorial is difficult

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi I'm a novice in cakephp and also I just finished reading the book "Php and Mysql for Beginners" by Lassoff.

So I'm totally newbie at programming.

However, I'm trying to make my blog with cakephp 3.0 which is newest version, I got stuck understanding some codes in the tutorial.

For example,

```
// src/Controller/ArticlesController.php

namespace App\Controller;

class ArticlesController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $articles = $this->Articles->find('all');
        $this->set(compact('articles'));
    }
}
```

I have no idea about the last two lines of code.

What i know is $article(variable) is declared and will store something by $this->Srticles->find('all')

and I don't know what is $this means and what is set() and what is ->

Please let me know or would you recommend something to read? like a book or something?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $this is the reference to class instance, you need to learn basics about object oriented programming, good luck!

Comment: you have to read about POO : Object Oriented Programming.$this->Articles->find('all') means retrieve all elements of articles from Database , $this->set('articles') means to set the results into a variable accessible in the view , which means you have to read also about MVC concept : Model View Controller.

Comment: Basically, you need more experience and learning. Within a PHP class, `$this` is a reference to the class itself. But there's a limit to how much can be explained within this Q&A format. Go read more! And good luck!

Comment: You should spend some time reading up on object oriented programming, or else you will struggle with cake

Comment: Care to check the answer?

Comment: @mcgowan.b Hi , Check his profile . He already read JAVA books.He knows it well.I think the problem is , he is new to Cakephp.

Comment: Thank you guys, I know little bit about java and php but I totally new to cake However, I think i have to read more about php to get used to it and then go cake. Thank you so much for everything guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clarify :

cakePHP uses Object Oriented coding .Uses ORM for Database mapping.
Object Relationship Model means it treats Table record as object.

1)

```
  $articles = $this->Articles->find('all');
```

Means For current Object , Goto table `article` which get associated by Model name `Article` ,And find All records.Store it in $articles. Its like `SELECT * FROM articles`.

2)

```
 $this->set(compact('articles'));
```

Here data fetched by current object Is set to send to view to render.And compact creates array from object.

For more on 2nd point check **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477696/cakephp-clarification-on-using-set-and-compact-together-will-only-work-w-c)**